# Data passage from activity to its view

Tags: android, android-activity, view

I Have an android activity with a custom view set to it. The custom view is a java class. I need to infer some methods of view from it's activity. How can I do this?

Comment: In addition to Scrinivasans answer: Please read the concepts of OOP and Java first, before programming for android if this was really your question. Or your question should rather be: How do I access views from activity - which is allready properly answered at overflow.

Answer (score 2):

1)Created CustomView class with extends of view(whatever you want)

2)Create a method within CustomView class like,

```
public void check(){
}
```

3)Use custom view in you xml or activity
4)Find the view from activity,

```
private CustomView  obj;
obj = (CustomView)findViewById(R.id.view1);
```

5)Now if i want to access the check method

```
obj.check();
```